# How can I change theme properties of selected unfocused items, they're difficult to read

Tags: themes, eclipse, ambiance

I like the default Ambiance theme but I spend a lot of time within Eclipse and there are portions that are unusable. The attached screenshot shows one example of this problem.

I tried using [Parasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/) to identify the widget class to modify but it isn't special, just GtkTreeView. So I'm hoping I just don't know the magic theme incantations.

I'm trying to make selected "unfocused" tree items have black text.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and now that its fixed, here is the solution:

1. Go to **Appearance Preferences**
2. Select **Theme** tab and click **Customize** button.
3. Go to Colors tab and change the color (which should be white) of **Text** column for **Selected Items** row.

Hope this will fix your problem.

Note: As this is Theme change it will be applied in other applications too, so choose your color so that it is visible properly under the **Background** color in the same row.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up taking a slightly different approach by making eclipse use a different theme that looks very similar to Ambiance but does not have the some selection issues.

`GTK2_RC_FILES=/path/to/other/theme/gtkrc /path/to/eclipse`

Comment: Your welcome. I am glad your problem is already resolved. May I ask which theme was used by you? Its definitely simple to just change the theme.

Comment: If you want to match Ubuntu's default theme I'd suggest the original Equinox Ambient theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way (works on 12.04): install and start **gnome-color-chooser**.
Then go to the first tab 'Global Colors', and in 'Entry Fields', change the Foreground for 'selected' (use a dark color).

This will also affect the color of the focused selection - I don't know if there is a way to only change the unfocused selection color, but actually it's all right because dark on orange is also readable.